# Is Tukey the best way to test for differences in slopes after a mixed-effect ANCOVA?

Tags: r

I have a fairly simple fitted model that looks like:

```
fm <- lmer(Height~Site*HW+(1|Plot))
```

where Height and HW are continuous variables and Site and Plot are categorical. Site has 3 levels (A, B, C) I ran a Type II Wald Chi square and it showed that the interaction term was significant, which I am interpreting as that sites differed in their Height vs HW slopes:

```
> Anova(fm)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Height
            Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Site       26.147  2    2.1e-06 ***
HW         91.089  1    < 2e-16 ***
Site:HW    13.775  2    0.00102 **
```

I'm interested in running a post-hoc to see which sites did and did not significantly differ in slope. I tried the following, but it doesn't look like a good match of what's going on visually when I plot the data. Is this the correct code?

```
leastsquare = lsmeans(fm,pairwise ~ Site:HW,adjust = "tukey")
leastsquare$contrasts

contrast     estimate     SE     df    t.ratio p.value
A - B        0.00206      0.0113 4.87  0.182   0.9819 
A - C       -0.04496      0.0101 4.88 -4.438   0.0163 
B - C       -0.04703      0.0113 4.87 -4.154   0.0212
```

So that's my first question: Is the above the correct way to test for slope differences among 3 levels of my categorical variable?

I am also interested in knowing how the means of the three site levels differ from one another (in addition to the slope question above). Can I just run a post-hoc tukey on Site? Is gives me warnings if I do this. Is there a better way to ask about main effects while taking into account the interaction?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That’s because the code shown compares means, not slopes. Look at the `emtrends` (or `lstrends`) function. Both are documented in the **emmeans** package.

```
emt = emtrends(fm, “Site”, var = HW)
emt    # estimated slopes
pairs(emt)    # pairwise comparisons
```